# Can you reference a SASS function from another file without importing everything?

Tags: css, sass

I'm very new to SASS and well web development altogether, I apologise in advance if this is obvious. I'm tyring to reference a function from one SASS file from another. I don't really want to import it as it would be import once again in the parent file.

My file structure:

stylesheets/custom.scss

stylesheets/scss/_auth.scss

stylesheets/scss/_account.scss

I have some functions in main.scss which I want to use from _auth.scss for example. The problem I'm having is that the custom.scss imports the other scss to combine them. I didn't want to make cross references.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Once again I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move the function and mixins in one file. And import them in main SCSS file(on the top) where all SCSS is getting imported.
By doing this you won't need to import functions separately in other files.
e.g:
custom.scss already imported main.scss. Functions declared in main.scss will available in _auth.scss file also.

```
stylesheets/custom.scss
  @import 'main.scss';
  @import 'scss/_auth.scss';
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I can't upvote due to low reputation.